# How to detect free variable names in R functions

Tags: r

Suppose I have a function:

```
f <- function() {
  x + 1
}
```

Here `x` is a free variable since its value is not defined within function `f`. 
Is there a way that I can obtain the variable name, say `x`, from a defined function, say `f`?

I am asking this question while maintaining others' old R codes. There are a lot of free variables used, and that makes debugging hard.

Any suggestions are welcomed as well.

Comment: `?body`. Try: `body(f)`

Comment: @BondedDust `body(f)` lists the definition, but does not give the free variable names. When `f` is very long, `body(f)` is very hard to use.

Comment: @Dason, at least I could not find a duplicated question in stackoverflow. If you can find it later, please mention it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [codetools](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/codetools/index.html) package has functions for this purpose, eg `findGlobals`

```
findGlobals(f, merge=FALSE)[['variables']]
# [1] "x"
```

if we redefine the function to have a named argument `x` then no variables are returned.

```
f2 <- function(x){
  x+1
}
findGlobals(f2, merge=FALSE)[['variables']]
# character(0)
```

Comment: Thanks @mnel for pointing me this helpful function.

Comment: And thanks for providing the search strategy to find the duplicate, which was also closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

This is a rough stab at it.

```
find_vars <- function(f, vars=list(found=character(), defined=names(formals(f)))) {
    if( is.function(f) ) {
        # function, begin search on body
        return(find_vars(body(f), vars))
    } else if (is.call(f) && deparse(f[[1]]) == "<-") {
        # assignment with <- operator
        if (is.recursive(f[[2]])) {
           if (is.call(f[[2]]) && deparse(f[[2]][[1]]) == "$") {
               vars$defined <- unique( c(vars$defined, deparse(f[[2]][[1]])) )  
           } else {
               warning(paste("unable to determine assignments variable in", deparse(f[[2]])))
           }
        } else {
            vars$defined <- unique( c(vars$defined, deparse(f[[2]])) )  
        }
        vars <- find_vars(f[[3]], vars)
    } else if (is.call(f) && deparse(f[[1]]) == "$") {
        # assume "b" is ok in a$b
        vars <- find_vars(f[[2]], vars)
    } else if (is.call(f) && deparse(f[[1]]) == "~") {
        #skip formulas
    } else if (is.recursive(f)) {
        # compound object, iterate through sub-parts
        v <- lapply(as.list(f)[-1], find_vars, vars)
        vars$defined <- unique( c(vars$defined, unlist(sapply(v, `[[`, "defined"))) )
        vars$found <- unique( c(vars$found, unlist(sapply(v, `[[`, "found"))) )
    } else if (is(f, "name")) {
        # standard variable name/symbol
        vars$found <- unique( c(vars$found, deparse(f)))
    }
    vars
}

find_free <- function(f) {
    r <- find_vars(f)
    return(setdiff(r$found, r$defined))
}
```

Then you could use it like

```
f <- function() {
  z <- x + 1
  z
}
find_free(f)
# [1] "x"
```

I'm sure there are many possibilities for a false positives and I didn't do any special coding for functions with non standard evaluation. For example

```
g <- function(df) {
  with(df, mpg + disp)
}
g(head(mtcars))
# [1] 181 181 131 279 379 243
```

but

```
find_free(g)
# [1] "mpg"  "disp"
```

I already put in a special branch for the `$` operator and formulas; you could put in a special branch for functions that have non standard evaluation like `with()` or `subset()` or whatever you like. It depends on what your code ends up looking like.

This assumes all assignment is happening via a standard `<-`. There are other ways to assign variables (ie, `assign()`) that would go undetected. We also ignore all function calls. So if you call `myfun(1)`, it will not report `myfun` as being a free variable even though it may potentially be a "free function" defined else where in the code.

So this may not be perfect, but it should act as a decent screen for potential problems.

Comment: Thanks for this illustrative code. I learned a lot from you again. It works perfectly.

Comment: `find_free` definitely meets my needs. Just FYI, this is a corner case, `f <- function() {summary(c(1))$Mean}`, I expect the results to be empty, but I got `[1] "summary(c(1))"`. Again, it does not affect my usage at all. Thank you.

Comment: @zhanxw I made a small adjustment for the code in your example. Likely I said, it may need further adjustments to be perfect. I assume `findGlobals` in `codetools` is more complete.

Comment: Thanks @MrFlick. It works. I am using both now.