# How to find *all* lexically referenced variables hidden inside of functions?

Tags: r, eval, non-standard-evaluation

I am trying to extract out all symbols inside the body of a function which were not defined in that function, but which were defined somewhere up the environment stack. I originally thought that I could do this using the return value of `codetools::findGlobals`, but apparently this function doesn't do exactly what I thought since it misses variables referenced inside of a quoted expression. See the reproducible example below:

```
x = 2
y = 1
hidden = function() {
  eval(quote({ x + y }))
}
revealed = function() {
  x + y
}
codetools::findGlobals(hidden)
codetools::findGlobals(revealed)
```

Given this limitation of `findGlobals`, is there a preferred alternative technique?

Comment: This really isn't possible in the general case without actually executing code. I mean if you did something like `eval(as.name(paste0("a","b")))` this would still be hard to detect because you are dynamically building code. But in this case, the function [`find_vars()` from another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25374640/2372064) would do what you want and extract all those symbols.